# I am new on Tor I need help with traces

Tags: anonymity, tails, windows

I am new to Tor.  I don't know if Tor saves my cache, cookies or any kind of data locally on my PC. I don't want to use Tails OS as it takes long to boot. I know that I can delete cookies and all kinds of data later then overwrite my drive, but that takes a long time as well. So do you have any ideas that can help me?

Comment: Read the manual. Without understanding what tor is and is not, it wont help you stay anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

> I am new on TOR, I don't know if TOR saves my cache, cookies or any
>   kind of data locally on my pc

They are saved into RAM only as long as the browser is working otherwise most websites would not work because they require cookies.

When you close all browser tabs and windows, they are gone.

> So do you guys have any ideas that can help me?

Mostly just [read the docs](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/documentation.html.en) and understand what [Tor and Tor Browser is](https://2019.www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en) and how it works.